# Weird Text Issue Showing on Page 2 on SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working through a weird text issue. I am laying out a bill and everything works except for 3 text areas that are being stubborn. They only show up on page 2 when they should be on page 1. It should be a one-page document. I am using a list object to put all of these elements onto. It worked before I put it on the list, but I was only able to print one bill. There are hundreds of bills that will be printed, so I changed it to a list, and now this.

Here is Page 1 of the PDF that gets generated from the report. Printing does the same thing.
[image: PDF Page 1]

Here is page 2 with two titles (one is cut off for brevity) and some boilerplate text.
[image: PDF Page 2]

Here is what I intend it to look like.
[image: What I designed]

I am not sure where to go from here. It isn't making any sense and searching for this exact issue hasn't turned up anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely has to do with your report being wider than the printing layout. Take a look at the report properties and the body properties.

Right click outside the report body and click Report Properties. Under Page Setup, take note of your settings for width and L/R margins. For example, if the page is set to landscape and paper size is letter, then width would probably be 11 in. with .5 in. left and right margin as default. This means your report body length cannot be more than 10 in. (11 in. - (.5 in. + .5 in.) ) if you want your text to fit on one page.

Open the Properties window (F4) and click in the body of the report. There should be a size section and you can type in 10 for the Width. Make sure you are in the report body. If it doesn't let you, then you might have some objects that are in the way, such as the "CITY LICENSE RENEWAL NOTICE" textbox and everything underneath.

Also in looking at your layout, you can move everything left a little bit so they are flush with the border. The margins is already defined in the report properties so you do not need to manually this. You might end up with extra white space.

Comment: ...and here I thought I was being careful to not change that. In moving things around I must have accidentally changed that. This was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! When you preview the report in visual studio, there is a "Print Layout" (right of the print icon) icon in the toolbar. You can use this to see what it will look like in PDF view and you wouldn't need to save it to PDF each time to review the format